# HTML/Javascript proper way for an element to call a function onclick

Tags: javascript, html

Suppose I have a function

```
function foo(a, b, c)
{
   // ...
}
```

that I want a button to call. I know that the way to call foo if it were a parameterless function would be

`onclick="foo()"`

but what is the way to do it when the function has parameters? Is it simply

```
onclick="foo(a,b,c)"
```

????

That seems awkward to have a string that gets interpreted as a function call. And does that even work? Or what is the way to do what I'm trying to do?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5871640/why-is-using-onclick-in-html-a-bad-practice Check this out

Comment: What are a, b, and c? Does the function need them?

Answer (score 0):

Your example would be the correct way to do it, assuming `a`, `b`, and `c` are variables defined in the window scope. To pass specific values for a, b, and c you'd do something like `onclick="foo('bar', 'baz', 'quux')"`. The "magic" form `onclick="foo(event)"` will pass in the [Event object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event) containing details about e.g. what button was clicked and where.

Answer (score 0):

You can't call without parameters, unless you do this :

```
function foo(/*a,b,c*/){
    some stuff
}
```

Or

```
function foo(){
    some stuff
}
```

Or

```
onclick="foo(a,b,c)"
```

So you assign some value to use the function.

Comment: are you sure you cant call a function without the params, even if the declaration includes params?

Comment: You assign some values => okay